# Is there a way to import train_test_ spit in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am getting this error after I run my test. This is beyond frusterating.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3cd21e54f349> in <module>()
     81 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
     82 from sklearn import preprocessing
---> 83 from sklearn.feature_selection import train_test_split
     84 
     85 

ImportError: cannot import name 'train_test_split'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

Comment: Not a `tensorflow2.0` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Before rushing to open a question here, it is assumed that you have first checked the relevant [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html); had you done so, you would have discovered that `train_test_split` is under the `sklearn.model_selection` module, and not the `sklearn.feature_selection` one.

Comment: Well?? Did you try `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` instead?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you did not use pip to install sklearn. In the terminal you should run:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

and make sure it runs without errors.

Comment: Please notice that the previous line `from sklearn import preprocessing` executes OK, so it is not that.